# How to decide on travel to possible Zika zone while pregnant

Tags: obstetrics, risks, zika-virus, geography, travel

Anyone with first hand knowledge about traveling to Argentina while 4 months pregnant? The [CDC](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/notices/alert/zika-virus-argentina) states that Argentina is a Level 2 Alert country (Practice Enhanced Precautions) and pregnant women should not go there. However I wonder if this is an overly cautious approach.

The places of interest would be urban settings in Buenos Aires (city), Mar del Plata (seaside), Bariloche (Patagonia), and possibly Corrientes/Resistencia (northeast).